# Visual Studio Code C++ debugger doesn't launch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Try to launch a c++ project, chose `gdb` launcher

`launch.json`

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe your `"/path/to/gdb"` is wrong.

Comment: should i change it manualy in json file or what?

Comment: Yes edit launch.json like the documentation shows: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: where can i find gdb file or folder?

Comment: That depends on where you put it and  how you installed your compiler. You may want to look at your filesystem and search for gdb.exe